# Batch command to get a txt name, and then set the first word of that TXT in varible

Tags: batch-file

I'm having a problem to read a file in the batch script and then set the first word of that file into a variable, and then I'll use it later.

My code is:

```
set /p file= | dir /b .\*.txt

for /f "delims=-" %%i in (%file%) do set %db_sid%=%%i 
pause
```

I need to read the file and set just the first word as a `db_sid` variable.

This is the current content of the text:

> ```
> prod11i-sarasa
> ```

I want `db_sid` to be just `prod11i`.

Comment: Change `set %db_sid%=%%i` to `set db_sid=%%i`, or even better, `set "db_sid=%%i"`. What is the first line of your code supposed to do? should it gather the name of the (first) found text file? if so, use `for %%j in (.\*.txt) do set "file=%%j"` instead...

Comment: Is there only one .txt file in your folder?

Comment: The first line must get the name of the txt, so it can be used in the for, and then get that first word in txt by reading it and place in the variable " db_sid "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to get the first line of the text file, which is done by `set /p var=<file`. Then you can split the string with a `for /f` (or alternatively cut the second part off with string manipulation, but since the `*` is only supported as first character, you would need to make that twice using a temporary variable).

```
for /f "tokens=* delims="  %%F in ('dir/b *.txt') do set /P db_sid=<"%%~fF" 
for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%W in ("%db_sid%") do set "db_sid=%%W"
```

Comment: Your 1st `for /f` will process ***all*** .txt files, not just the first. `db-sid` will contain the 1st word of the last file.

Comment: Wow this really worked for me thank you very much!!

Comment: @LotPings Yes I know that ... and where is the problem? Daniel only said: "I'm having a problem to read **a file** in the batch script and then [...]"

Comment: @timlg07 You are right, I meant the 1st `for`. In OPs code try the first line would (if that had worked) get just the first file from the `dir`, looks like I did over interpret that.

Comment: @LotPings Yeah that's true, I will edit that later :)

Comment: @LotPings A bit longer, but it now uses `dir`, like OP wanted it ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first word of the first file you'll need to exit the for with a goto.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\06\06\SO_5640691.cmd
@Echo on
for %%F in (*.txt) do for /f "usebackq delims=-" %%W in ("%%F") do set "db_sid=%%W"&goto :Out
:Out
Set db_sid
```